# Is 'git --bare init' wrong?

Tags: git

Is `git --bare init` wrong?

Should it be:

```
git init --bare
```

Comment: What do you mean? Both work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a semantical point of view, `git init --bare` is better : `--bare` is related to init, not the entire git.

Answer (score 19):

`git --bare init` is not wrong, it is just a different way to express the same (bugs notwithstanding) operation.

As a quick look at the toplevel [git(1) manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) will confirm, `--bare` is a global option for all Git commands which affects how the repository directory is discovered:

```
   --bare
       Treat the repository as a bare repository. If GIT_DIR environment
       is not set, it is set to the current working directory.
```

Originally, this was the only way to have git commands operate in "bare mode", which is why you'll find `git --bare init` in quite a lot of the older documents/tutorials. `--bare` as separate option was added in the 1.5.6 series, to improve the CLI.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck using an older version of git on a specific machine & this reminded me to use git --bare init, instead of git init --bare (which did not work)

Answer (score 2):

to initialize a d git repository the  best command i am using is

```
git init --bare .
```

before execute this command make sure you are inside in your directory which one you want to create repository.